# HAProxy balance algorithms for Apache and MySQL

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, haproxy

just recently I got responsible for an existing project that uses Apache webservers and MySQL databases.

The webserver are behind a HAProxy loadbalancer and the application connects to the MySQL slaves via another HAProxy.

2 of the 10 webserver were added just recently and are more powerful than the old ones.  The same for the MySQL slaves: 2 of these 5 slaves have more RAM and CPUs.

The balancing algorithm for the Apache servers is *leastconn* and for the slaves is *source*.  At least the settings for the MySQL servers I find odd because in the worst case the "best" apache (with the most weight) can always pick the worst MySQL server if I understand the [HAProxy Docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#balance) right.  I'd pick *roundrobin* with adjusted weights:

- 10 for the three normal MySQL server
- 20 for the two stronger MySQL server

And because the apaches are behind the HAProxy with a 20s timeout, I'd rather apply *roundrobin*, too.

- 10 for the eight normal apache server
- 20 for the more powerfull apache server

(I would use the 20 just for a start.  I'm going to watch the monitoring and will have it adjusted later.)

Because the the servers are in colocation (as in: I have not root access, change requests take some time) I'd just like to have a second (or more) opinion on this topic:  is it a good idea to change the balancing algorithm for both to *roundrobin* ?  I wouldn't consider this if there weren't any performance problems just recently and this is just one place that I find worth tweaking.

Thanks for any/ your advice!

Regards
dennis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` is indeed an odd choice, unless your appservers are supposed to have session persistence with DB slaves. That's for you to figure out, though.

`leastconn` is usually a very good choice if performance of each server (both appserver and database) is not absolutely steady. This depends on the details of your application and platform. (E.g., a Java based appserver can have periods of slow-down due to garbage collection, during which it is sensible to decrease its balancing load.)

Finally, yes, with `roundrobin` you will usually achieve very predictable and stable balancing that adheres tightly to the weightings.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Especially the hint at the session persistence.